# Images of sections of a sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

I'm currently reading a [paper by X. Caicedo](http://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/archivos/publicaciones/Logicadeloshacesdeestructura.pdf) containing an introduction to sheaves.
On page 8 he claims, that for every sheaf of sets $p:E\to X$ and every section $\sigma:U\to E$ (U being open in X) the image $\sigma(U)$ is open.
This statement is proved by picking a point $e\in\sigma(U)$, an open neighborhood S of e, which satisfies

1. $p(S)$ is open in X,
2. $p\restriction S$ is a homeomorphism

and arriving at an open set $\sigma(U)\supseteq S\cap\sigma(U)=p^{-1}(p(S)\cap U)$.

I think the "$\supseteq$" part of this equation does not hold, if for example E is equipped with the discrete topology and the stalk of $p(e)$ has more than one element.

I have tried to show that $(p\restriction S)^{-1}(p(S)\cap U) = p^{-1}(U)\cap S$ is contained in $\sigma(U)$, but all attempts at that felt quite clumsy, leading me to believe I have missed something important about the structure of a sheaf.

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion $\sigma(U)\supseteq S\cap\sigma(U)$ is trivially true.
The equality $S\cap\sigma(U)=p^{-1}(p(S)\cap U)$ is false in general.
For a counterexample take any $X$ and $$E=X\times \lbrace 1,2\rbrace \:,p(x,i)=x\:,  U=X\:, \sigma (x)=(x,1)\:, S=X\times \lbrace 1\rbrace$$ where   $\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$  has the discrete topology.
You then have $S\cap\sigma(U)=S\neq   p^{-1}(p(S)\cap U)=p^{-1}(X)=E   $

Comment: That's similar to what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove $\sigma(U)$ is open, since $p(S)\cap U$ is open in $X$ and $p|S$ is a homeomorphism, it suffices to show $p|S(S\cap \sigma(U))=p(S)\cap U$. Clearly, this is true($p\sigma(u)=u$, for $u\in U$).